# Testing a PORO in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I use Rspec to test my Rails app. In my Model directory I have a Ruby file called location_services.rb. In this file is

```
module LocationServices
  class IpLocator
     attr_reader :response, :status
     def initialize(response, status)
       ....
     end
end
```

How can I test the creation of an IpLocator object all by itself? I just want to be able to call IpLocator.create_type_1.response and test what I get whithout the whole rails stack.

create_type_1 is a class method on IpLocator that will call new to instansiate an object.

Comment: Need more information. What exactly are you trying to test? That the object was created while performing some other operation? A broader context would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your file looks more like this:

```
module LocationServices
  class IpLocator
    attr_reader :response, :status
    def initialize(response, status)
      ....
    end

    def self.create_type_1
      self.new
      # Possibly some more code here
    end
  end
end
```

You could create `spec/models/location_services_spec.rb` and structure it like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LocationServices::IpLocator do
  describe '.create_type_1' do
    locator = LocationServices::IpLocator.create_type_1
    expect(locator).to # finish your assertion here
  end
end
```

The naming conventions might not work quite right. If RSpec doesn't find the class it needs, you could try moving and renaming `location_services.rb` to `app/models/location_services/ip_locator.rb`. Move and rename the spec to `spec/models/location_services/ip_locator_spec.rb` if you do that.

Requiring the `spec_helper.rb` file might load the Rails stack for your tests, though. That might depend on how your file is set up.